# PHP: dynamically get name of a class that extends the current class

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have an abstract class and an extending class:

```
abstract class MyAbstract {
    public function getName(){echo static::class;}
}

class MyExtends extends MyAbstract {}
```

I would like to dynamically get the name of any extending class when `getName()` is called:

```
$c = new MyExtends();
echo $c->getName(); // expect: "MyExtends"
```

This works well on PHP 5.6+ ([demo](https://3v4l.org/LsThs)), but the project I'm working on is limited to PHP 5.3 and I have no leverage to change that. On that version, a parse error is thrown:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'

So I modified the function to:

```
public function getName(){echo __CLASS__;}
```

Of course, this just echoes the parent name -- `MyAbstract`, so it doesn't work.  Only thing I've thought of is to override `getName()` with a new implementation in each extending class, but that doesn't scale well: the whole point of inheritance is to concentrate common codebase in a parent (and of course the real function is not a one-liner).

Any idea how I can dynamically get the extending class name from the context of the abstract parent class in PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the name of class:

```
<?php
abstract class MyAbstract
{
    public function getName()
    {
        echo get_class($this);
    }
}

class MyExtends extends MyAbstract 
{
}

$c = new MyExtends();
echo $c->getName(); // expect: "MyExtends"
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/TtMtZ7

The above code should work on all versions (since 5.0.4).

Comment: Thank you. yes it works as expected. Please add a link to the docs to improve the answer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: @BeetleJuice - link was available but in german :P - changed to english. thx.

Comment: Cool site (ideone.com); I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
public function getName(){get_class($this);}
```

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Your instinct is correct. It works

Comment: Excellent. Good luck